# Completing a Promise[T] with Async in Scala and Play2

Tags: scala, concurrency, playframework-2.0, future, promise

I am trying to complete a Promise[String] for my Action. So far I've read the Play's documentation on asynchronous programming at http://www.playframework.com/documentation/2.0/ScalaAsync but there's something I am not getting - or the docs are wrong :)

Here's an outline of my code. My intention is to return a Promise[String] and complete that in my Action. The content of the Promise may come from different places, so I would like to be able to return a Promise[String] to have the Action handler simple.

```
def getJson = Action { request =>
  val promiseOfJson = models.item.getJson
  Async {
    promiseOfJson.map(json => Ok(json))
  }   
}

def models.item.getJson: Promise[String] = {
  val resultPromise = promise[String]
  future {
     ...
     resultPromise success "Foo"
  }

  resultPromise
}
```

Looking at Play's documentation and at "AsyncResult" I think I am doing the same thing, no?

Problem is that I get a compilation error inside my Async {} block:

> value map is not a member of scala.concurrent.Promise[String]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Turns out that Play fundamentally changed how Asyncs work between Play versions 2.0 and 2.1.

By Googling "Play Async" you first get the docs for version 2.0, which is why my above code won't work. **This is the outdated version of the docs!**

In Play 2.1 (docs are here: http://www.playframework.com/documentation/2.1.0/ScalaAsync) the Async completes a Future[T] instead of Promise[T]. In Play 2.0 Async completes a Promise[T], which is what I had (but I am running Play 2.1).

I changed my code to this and it works as expected:

```
def models.item.getJson: Future[String] = {
  val resultPromise = promise[String]
  future {
     ...
     resultPromise success "Foo"
  }

  resultPromise.future
}
```

Comment: The reason for this change is that Scala 2.10 now is used and it has got a Future/Promise API as a part of the standard library. Play now uses that instead of its own implementation.

Comment: Not sure if this is related or not, but I run Scala 2.9.1 as that's only available on Ubuntu 12.04.

Comment: Play contains it's own bundled scala version that it uses so you actually don't even have to install Scala to be able to code play/scala.

Comment: Yeah - I noticed that after I wrote the comment :) "play console" shows that the Play's Scala version I actually used is 2.10.

Comment: How to handle the errors thrown in future block of models.item.getJson